# Using AWS Kinesis Firehose in Multi tenant environment

Tags: multi-tenant, amazon-kinesis

Are there any recommendations on how we can use AWS Kinesis Firehose where data/events are published from different applications from customer’s environment (multiple customers or tenants)?

Our application continuously  generate events which we want to ingest into cloud solution for processing. We are evaluating if AWS Kinesis Firehose delivery stream as entry point. Since it is a multi tenant solution we are trying to find case studies to understand how data can be partitioned if we use Firehose for data ingestion.

Thanks,
Vishnu.

Comment: Currently that might be a problem as i understand, the options are - either introduce IoT beforehand, and enrich the incoming data with the tenants (using iot rules), sign the messages in customer side with a key per tenant (also IoT can assist here)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @vishnu pedasingu